# How can I put my name in the lower corner of my pictures using photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photography

How can I put my name in the lower corner of my pictures using Photoshop? Specifically, how can I put my name in mass numbers of my pictures using Photoshop? I have 1500 photos from a recent biology trip that need my name in them so people know that the works are mine. I can do it one by one, but is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch processing.
Not sure which version of PS you're using, but try File > Automate > Batch.

You'll need two folders, one with all your original images, and another empty one to dump the edited versions in. You select these folder destinations, record the edits you want (in your case, you''l add text in the corner, or your logo or whatever) and then you run the batch.

PS will look like it's going a bit crazy for a while - opening each file, adding the text and saving it into the new destination folder, but don't worry. It's doing it automatically.